# Interpretation of "If $Ax=b$, then $b$ is a linear combination of the columns of $A$."

Tags: linear-algebra

"If $Ax=b$, then $b$ is a linear combination of the columns of $A$."

Is there any conceivable valid way that the above sentence could be construed to be false? (Given reasonable assumptions coming from the fact that this is a question from an intro to linear algebra class.)

Comment: The sentence could be false if $A$ is not a matrix

Comment: That's what I meant by reasonable assumptions, but let's say A is a finite dimensional real matrix and b,x are real vectors of appropriate dimensions.

Comment: if $Ax$ denotes something else than the matrix multiplication you might have a chance, otherwise let $A=(a_1|...|a_n)$ and you would have $b=x_1\cdot a_1+...+x_n\cdot a_n.$

Answer (score 0):

You can check that matrix multiplication equals
$$
          Ax=\left[\begin{array}{ccccc}
                    a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & a_{1,3} & \cdots & a_{1,m} \\
                    a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & a_{2,3} & \cdots & a_{2,m} \\
                    a_{3,1} & a_{3,2} & a_{3,3} & \cdots & a_{3,m} \\
                      \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
                    a_{n,1} & a_{n,2} & a_{n,3} & \cdots & a_{n,m}
                  \end{array}\right]
             \left[\begin{array}{c}x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ x_4 \\ \vdots \\x_m\end{array}\right] \\
  = x_1\left[\begin{array}{c}a_{1,1} \\ a_{2,1} \\ a_{3,1} \\ \vdots \\ a_{n,1}\end{array}\right]+
    x_2\left[\begin{array}{c}a_{1,2} \\ a_{2,2} \\ a_{3,2} \\ \vdots \\ a_{n,2}\end{array}\right]+
      \cdots+
    x_m\left[\begin{array}{c}a_{1,m} \\ a_{2,m} \\ a_{3,m} \\ \vdots \\ a_{n,m}\end{array}\right]
$$
One way to think about that kind of multiplication is that you turn the column vector $x$ counterclockwise until it is horizontal, and you dump out the constants in front of the corresponding columns of the matrix $A$. So $Ax$ becomes a linear combination of the columns of $A$. The range of $A$ is spanned by the column vectors of $A$. The column space of $A$ is the range of $A$.